# Using jquery to select a form through a button

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm trying to use jquery to select my form and post it to a controller (my controller is called PartOverride) method (called SubmitOverrides) and I can't get the form to serialize properly. Here's my jquery function:

```
            var url = _root.ConcatUrl('PartOverride/SubmitOverrides');
            var form = $('#lowerSubmitButton').parents();
            $.post(url, function (htmlResult) {
            $(form).html(htmlResult);
```

Note: "LowerSubmitButton" is the ID of my button that calls the function to submit the form.

Comment: try to use a var str = $( "form" ).serialize();
this will be get all form data ... and set it in htmlResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the data to be posted as the second argument for $.post(). You can use the serialize method (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to do that.

```
    var url = _root.ConcatUrl('PartOverride/SubmitOverrides');
    var form = $('#lowerSubmitButton').parent(); // it's 'parent' and not 'parents'
    var data = form.serialize();
    $.post(url, data, function (htmlResult) {
        $(form).html(htmlResult);  
    });
```

You can also directly submit a form using the .submit() method (http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: Happy to see that it helped you. :)